# how to get a google+ hangout video live link to show in iframe without youtube logo

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

i created a google hangout app.
but now i want to broadcast my google+ hangout OnAir video.
i got the video embed link and i pasted it in iframe.
like

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WE6UGi2-vAA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then i got the video , screenshot of that video is [here](http://s18.postimg.org/6sb2netll/youtube_live.png) !

but i don't want the youtube link and logo in that broadcast, how can i get the video embed without youtube link
and after completion of hangout onair live,the iframe shows the youtube videos like [this](http://s12.postimg.org/97bq3f78t/youtube_after.png)
can anyone tell me the process how to get the embed live video link without youtube link?

Comment: There is no way to remove youtube logo AFAIK, as Google wants youtube logo to be there.

Comment: Thank you @JonasCz  ,i have one question, can i remove like and dislike, share icons from the video? if i can !, what is the process? .

Comment: Check [this](http://leaderswest.com/2012/10/10/youtube-embed-options-can-make-your-videos-look-less-youtube-y/). Actually you _can_ remove a lot of the stuff.